# Comparing unicode representations to symbols

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I have a datafile containing a large number of sentences, encoded like this:

"Gib mir bitte Erk\u00e4ltung"

I also have a datafile containing a large number of keywords, encoded like this:

"Erkältung"

I would like to search for keywords in sentences and then write them out to a file, in the "Erkältung" format.

How would I convert \u00e4 to ä without having to do:

String.replace('\u00e4', 'ä')

More exactly, I would like to have this return a match in Python 2.6:

(#coding: utf-8)

```
sentence = "Gib mir bitte Erk\u00e4ltung"

keyword = "Erkältung"

re.search(keyword, line)
```

Any hints?

Comment: If all you need to do is a substring search on static text, `keyword in sentence` is usually a better choice than regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has some handy character encoding conversions built in.  In this case `unicode_escape` is what you want.  When you read in your sentence, convert it as follows prior to doing your search:

```
# Original sentence:

>>> s = "Gib mir bitte Erk\u00e4ltung"

>>> print s
Gib mir bitte Erk\u00e4ltung

>>> print repr(s)
'Gib mir bitte Erk\\u00e4ltung'


# Converted sentence:

>>> sc = s.decode('unicode_escape')

>>> print sc
Gib mir bitte Erkältung

>>> print repr(sc)
u'Gib mir bitte Erk\xe4ltung'
```

Comment: This works for printing out, but does not seem to make the re.search work. As in: doing sentence.decode('unicode_escape') first, then re.search(keyword,sentence) does not result in a match.

Comment: `re` has some encoding directives you can provide as arguments that may help you out.  Though as I mentioned above, a simple `in` check may be a better choice anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately, the actual regex is much more complicated then this example and therefore does not allow for a simple in check. I tried encoding arguments for re, but have not had any success so far.

Comment: It's probably not working because you're comparing regular strings (`'str'`) to Unicode strings (`u'str'`).  Make sure your keyword is a Unicode string.

Comment: Success! Thanks for your help, dkamins. :)

Answer (score 1):

To read file with `\u00e4` encoded characters use

```
fp = open('sentence.txt', 'r')
sentence = fp.read().decode('unicode-escape')
fp.close()
print repr(sentence) # -> u'Gib mir bitte Erk\xe4ltung'
```

Then read file without escaping:

```
import codecs
fp = codecs.open('keyword.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
keyword = fp.read()
fp.close()
print repr(keyword) # -> u'Erk\xe4ltung'
```

Then you have both in same format

```
fp = codecs.open('result.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8')
if re.search(keyword, sentence, re.UNICODE) :
    fp.write(sentence)
fp.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-regex solution (preferred):

```
s = s.decode('unicode_escape')
```

Regex solution:

```
s = re.sub(r'\\u([a-fA-F0-9]{4})', lambda m: unichr(int(m.group(1), 16)), s)
```